# Can "On a second look ..." be used in a sentence?

Tags: sentence

Is "On a second look, I thought / I felt" a correct usage?

The complete sentence will be like this: "On a second look, I thought that the IP address you provided belongs to another network range which is already allocated".

Comment: `At a second glance` is more idiomatic, but sounds weird when it starts a sentence

Comment: You may say: On a second thought, I realised that the IP Address...

Comment: Or change it entirely, as to not appear like you didn't look properly the first time. "After looking further into this, the IP address you provided appears to belong to another network range..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd change it entirely, as to not appear like you didn't look properly the first time.

"After looking further into this, the IP address you provided appears to belong to another network range..."

Also, I wouldn't use the word "felt", as that suggests it was an emotional response. You're an IT guy, you work on logic and information, not emotional responses. So you thought it, you didn't feel it.

Answer (score -2):

If you really thought so, use "thought", if you merely felt so, use "felt".

Comment: Thought and felt are not indicators of severity, they're completely different words. Thought is the past tense of think. Felt is the past tense of feel. "I think Dave feels upset", "I thought Dave felt upset".